# Can I play Call of Duty: Black Ops III on virtual LAN?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-3

I would like to know if there is any way to play Call of Duty: Black Ops III friends in virtual LAN.
I usually play Minecraft with some friends with Hamachi — is there any way to play Call of Duty: Black Ops III in a similar way, in a kind of virtual LAN like with Minecraft, perhaps with the help of some software like Hamachi?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it, Steam itself provides a very comprehensive guide on how to set it up: https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=814090509

Long story short:

- In Steam, find **Call of Duty: Black Ops III - Dedicated Server** and **Call of Duty: Black Ops III - Remote Console** (the latter is the admining tool)
- Server files can be found in your game dir, usually *C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Call of Duty Black Ops III*
- There will be a **Launch_Server.bat** which contains a few startup variables that you will want to change (map playlist, server name, password etc)
- The playlist itself is another file of interest (map rotation, gamemodes etc), in **machinecfg\playlists.info**
- There is of course way more, but these are the basics.

And a couple of notes:

- Although you can probably run this separately on your gaming machine, this works best on a **separate PC**. The rcon (admin) tool that you installed from Steam makes it possible to remotely manage it once it's running (changing maps, kicking unwanted players etc). The server PC can be a little older (a regular server will require fewer resources than the full client), but will also need Steam.
- You can set a **password** using +set live_steam_server_password "password", which would keep people out if you just open it up to the internet (which would also involve port forwarding on your router). For security reasons I would definitely run it on that VLAN that you share with your friends though.
- Always make sure you have a **backup** of a working configuration (Launch_Server.bat, the playlists in the machinecfg dir etc). You don't need to copy the full dir, just the config files (and preferably keep a few versions back). A typo in these files can prevent the server from starting, this is an easy fallback option.